# C# connection string to HBase kerberised cluster

Tags: c#, hbase, asp.net-core-2.0, kerberos

I am trying to connect my C# core 2.2. application to Hbase kerberised cluster, by Garuda.Data package (it uses phoenix framework for connection and wraps it to IDbConnection interface).
 I'm having trouble to create a proper connectionString that will implement both IP addresses of cluster db and will be kerberised also. I think I have to connect to zookeeper server somehow, and only after that it would be possible to connect to Hbase.
How is it possible to configure kerberised connectionString to HBase?

```
        public void GarudaNew()
    {using (IDbConnection phConn = new PhoenixConnection())
        {
            phConn.ConnectionString = "Server=myIP;UserID=myUser;Password=myPass;RequestTimeout=30000";
            phConn.Open();
            using (IDbCommand cmd = phConn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM GARUDATEST";
                using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i)));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can connect only to one address (server name or IP), so there must be some kind of router, wich addres you will set to connection string

Comment: I'm not sure that router can be a solution, because the whole idea of HBase cluster is that it can provide as many server addresses as you need and you have to connect to whole quorum.